# Ubuntu server error al insertar cadena larga en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, apache, ubuntu

Hola estoy usando una instalación nueva de ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS, tengo problemas a la hora  de insertar un string en mysql, creo que necesita configuración y yo lo tengo por default.

El caso es que cuando envío un string por $_POST de más de 164 caracteres el fichero recibe la cadena pero mysqli no la inserta y me aparece este error:
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proeyecto\inc\agregar.php on line 19

Cuando envío una cadena corta de menos de 164 caracteres la inserción a la base de datos se cumple perfectamente... supongo que será algún ajuste de seguridad en Msql.

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Bastante extraño. Intenta cambiar el tipo de campo a longtext.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer según la documentación oficial de PHP es pasar a la función mysqli_error() como primer parámetro la conexión que estas usando, si no, esta función de ta el Warning que nombras, seguramente luego de poner eso podrás ver el error real.